# XSS-issue accessing REST API on other port than web server

Tags: jquery, rest, nginx, xss

I need some help. I have web server on domain.se:80 and a REST API on domain.se:8080. My web site is loaded from domain.se:80 and it's a single-page app so just one load is enough and subsequent calls are made to the REST API. When trying this out nothing happened. The app refused to make the call to my REST API. When reading about this, might this be considered a XSS problem? That the web browser sees it as a security risk that my REST API is on another port (8080) than where the site was loaded (80) since it is called by Javascript?

Anyone who recognise this issue? It must be a very common setup for single-page apps. I solved it with nginx, letting nginx expose port 80 and than pass requests to the REST API if the url starts with /api/v1, and all other requests are passed to the web server. But is feels like a work-around, and I would like to get nginx out of the way :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So you have two alternatives.

1. Do the proxy as you have done, which we do in all cases with tomcat on 8080
2. Use a jsonp call instead of straight json.  This done not cause xss issues.

You can read more about jsonp here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

I typically front tomcat in order to serve static components, load balance and security.

Thanks

Chris